# Rails model with array field, modify push method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I've been trying to find an answer to my question but so far no luck.
I have a model with an array field and I'd like method calls to happen when something gets pushed into the array.

```rb
class Shop::Order
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps    

  embeds_many :items,class_name: 'Shop::OrderItem', inverse_of: :order
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :items 

  field :price, type: Money, default: Money.new(0)
  field :untaxed_price, type: Money, default: Money.new(0)

end
```

So when doing `order.items << Shop::OrderItem.new(...)`
I'd like a method `foo` to be called.

EDIT: Add reason

So the reason for this is that I want to update the `price` and `untaxed_price` of an order each time an item is added to it.

Comment: If you suscribe what is the reason behind it we can maybe provide a even better way. At the moment it sounds like you want a notification every time a new item gets orderd. And if so its a better way to handle it via the database direct. Sorry if i pointed in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it need to happen as soon as you push it?  Or can it happen before you save the order?  If you can wait until you save, you can do this:

```
before_validate :update_tax_info

def update_tax_info
  if items_changed?
    calculate_tax #whatever that may be
  end
end
```

Throwing it in a validation would allow that callback to be called without saving.  You could call `@order.valid?` to update the tax information.

Answer (score 0):

I think monkey patching `<<` is a bad idea. I have two ideas:

- Use some kind of observer which listens on `create` of `OrderItem` and performs appropriate action
- Overwrite `OrderItem.create` method (or even better provide abstraction):

```

```
class OrderItem
  def add(params)
    if create(params)
      calculate_something
    end
  end
end
```

```

Answer (score 0):

This documentation gives you the range of choices that you have to implement the desired behavior: http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/callbacks.html

To paraphrase, you have the option of using callbacks like `before_save` and `before_update` to do your calculations, or you can implement an `Observer` class to do this for you.

You can also use the `changed` method to see if the items array has changed and whether you need to update the derived fields.

Here's some example code:

```
class OrderObserver < Mongoid::Observer 
  def before_save(order)
    do_something
  end
end
```

Do remember to instantiate your observer in application.rb using:

```
config.mongoid.observers = :order_observer
```